# Why isn't this podspec including sqlite library automatically?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, cocoapods

I'm trying to setup a podspec for my class and it doesn't seem to be including the sqlite library properly in my project. I have to manually link it when I use this pod. Did I setup the podspec improperly or do I need to do something in the project to have the sqlite library included automatically?

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|

  s.name               = "ABSQLite"
  s.version            = "1.1.0"
  s.summary            = "ABSQLite is an Objective-C wrapper to SQLite making it easy to use the database."
  s.homepage           = "https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite"
  s.license            = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author             = { "Aaron L. Bratcher" => "aaronbratcher1@gmail.com" }
  s.social_media_url   = "http://twitter.com/AaronLBratcher"
  s.source             = { :git => "https://github.com/AaronBratcher/ABSQLite.git", :tag => '1.1.0' }
  s.source_files       = 'Classes/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.library            = 'sqlite3'
  s.requires_arc = true

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try change `s.library` to `s.ios.library`
or use `s.libraries`

according to [podspec specification](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#libraries)

please tell me if this not work

Comment: Please add a little more explanation?